# Input Autofocus on type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, autofocus

Good Evening and thanks all in advance!

i have this input:

```
<div class="ref-control">
    <h3>Por Favor passe o passe o cartão pelo leitor</h3>
    <form>
        <label for="leitura-nim"> Leitura de Nim
            <input tabindex="99" autofocus type="text" name="leitura-nim" id="leitura_nim" />
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this input get's autofocus when the page is loaded, so far so good, my problem is, when the user click outside the input, i need it to become autofocus again when the user press a key on keyboard or when the input is recived from some device(it is the same as typing it is tested), so far i got this js, but it does not enable the focus on keypress.

```
var leituraNim = $('#leitura_nim');

leituraNim.on('keypress', function() {
    document.getElementById('leitura_nim').contentEditable = true;
    document.getElementById('leitura_nim').focus();


});
leituraNim.on('keyup', function() {

    if (leituraNim.value.length == 8) {
        leituraNim.submit();
    }
});
```

can you guys help me out?

thanks Rob

Comment: getElementId does not use `#` and leituraNim is a jQuery object and it does not have .value

Comment: i tried both with and without. but i am removing it now.

Comment: You are also going to be binding multiple keyup events to the element. Do not bind events inside of events.

Comment: ok i should first use the keypress one than the keyup one ?

Comment: Out of the input you have to bind the keypress event to the window/document instead of the box, since the keypress event only listen to the input field.

Comment: yes Tyr you were right, i should call the document instead of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like I have below. Note the extra `#form` ID tag for `<form id="form">`. I think what you're trying to achieve is focus on any keypress when the input is not already focused, if so, `$(document).on("keypress")` should do the trick.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keypress", function() {
    $("#leitura_nim").focus();
  });
  
  $("#leitura_nim").on("keyup", function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 8) {
      $("#form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ref-control" >
<h3>Por Favor passe o passe o cartão pelo leitor</h3>
<form id="form">
<label for="leitura-nim"> Leitura de Nim
<input tabindex="99" autofocus type="text" name="leitura-nim" id="leitura_nim"  />
</label>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    document.getElementById("leitura_nim").focus();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbyw0tav/1/) and I think this it is what you are looking for:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ref-control" >
   <h3>Por Favor passe o passe o cartão pelo leitor</h3>
   <form id="leitura-form">
      <label for="leitura-nim"> Leitura de Nim
      <input tabindex="99" autofocus type="text" name="leitura-nim" id="leitura_nim"/>
      </label>
   </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('keypress', function() {
  $('#leitura_nim').contentEditable = true;
  $('#leitura_nim').focus();
});

$('#leitura_nim').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 8) {
    $("#leitura-form").submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: this seems closer, but I would argue still having the `keyup` on a seperate event handler, seperately from document `keypress`

Comment: thanks, it work perfectly, it shows here what Tyr was saying on the comments on my post. when i changed into document and removed the getElementsById it worked fine. thanks all, you guys are the one that keep making me want to learn more about programming.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside is the DOM node of the element, so there is no need to look it up. `getElementById` does not use `#` and binding events inside others is a bad idea because on every keypresss you would bind another event. They do not get overwritten, and a jQuery object does not have a `.value`

```
var leituraNim = $('#leitura_nim');
leituraNim.on('keypress', function() {
    this.contentEditable=true;  //not sure what this will do since it is an input 
    this.focus();  //If keypress is executed, shouldn't it already be focused?
}).on("keyup", function () {
   if (this.val.length == 8) {
       leituraNim.submit();
   } 
});
```

And as my comments state, seems like the stuff inside of the keypress does not make sense. What you want to do is listen for keypress events that are NOT inside of the input.

```
var leituraNim = $('#leitura_nim');
leituraNim.on("keyup", function () {
   if (this.val.length == 8) {
       leituraNim.submit();
   } 
});

$(window).on("keydown", function (evt) {
    var cTarget = evt.currentTarget;  //check where event originated from
    if (cTarget.is(leituraNim)) return;  //if input, than ignore
    leituraNim.focus();  //if not than focus input
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
        document.getElementById('leitura_nim').focus();

    });
```